# Is Piwik triggering a call to the application server instead of the server where piwik is hosted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, matomo, piwiktracker

I have a rails server and this is a snip from the server log

```
Processing CustomController#my_action (for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-05-11 08:38:53) [GET]
Parameters: {"id"=>"12345", "action"=>"my_action", "controller"=>"custom"}
...
all the other stuff that gets logged
...
Completed in 251ms (View: 181, DB: 60) | 200 OK [https://myserver.com/custom/my_action/12345]
...
...

Processing CustomController#my_action (for 10.0.2.2 at 2018-05-11 08:38:55) [GET]
  Parameters: {"id"=>"12345", "r"=>"876646", "h"=>"16", "m"=>"16", "s"=>"51", "send_image"=>"1", "gears"=>"0", "cookie"=>"1", "gt_ms"=>"1174", "uid"=>"dummyemail@myserver.com", "realp"=>"0", "java"=>"0", "qt"=>"0", "urlref"=>"https://myserver.com/reporting/report_builder/", "controller"=>"custom", "action_name"=>"", "idsite"=>"", "rec"=>"1", "_idts"=>"1525949211", "_idn"=>"1", "_refts"=>"0", "res"=>"1280x720", "_id"=>"f2fe432581e2e376", "wma"=>"0", "fla"=>"0", "_idvc"=>"1", "_viewts"=>"1525949211", "dir"=>"0", "action"=>"my_action", "url"=>"https://myserver.com/custom/my_action/12345", "pdf"=>"1", "ag"=>"0"}
...
all other stuff
Completed in 227ms (View: 177, DB: 39) | 200 OK [https://myserver.com/custom/my_action/12345?action_name=&idsite=&rec=1&r=705226&h=16&m=16&s=52&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.com%2Fcustom%2Fmy_action%2F2408&urlref=https%3A%2F%2Fmyserver.com%2Freporting%2Freport_builder%2F&uid=ctl-support%40myserver.com&_id=f2fe432581e2e376&_idts=1525949212&_idvc=0&_idn=1&_refts=0&_viewts=&send_image=1&pdf=1&qt=0&realp=0&wma=0&dir=0&fla=0&java=0&gears=0&ag=0&cookie=1&res=1280x720>_ms=757]
```

The problem with the above log is, I see duplicate server calls made for a single action.

I see this only when piwik tracking script is loaded. However, if I monitor the network tab in the browser, I could see only one call to the application server(myserver.com) and one call to the piwik server (mypiwikserver.com).

What might be the cause of this and how to fix this ?

Comment: Later I found out that this is occurring due to initialising piwik in two different places (scripts). Adding a check if it's already initialised did the trick.